# Webservice restricted to a single thread?

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency, resteasy, wildfly

Today, while testing some code that was slow (had to wait for data from a slow source) in a RESTlet, I noticed that Wildfly would not allow me to start additional threads, and would only run the RESTlet itself in a single thread as well, meaning multiple connections had to wait for the previous one to finish.

Oddly enough, even using a `ManagedExecutorService`, configured through the `urn:jboss:domain:ee:3.0` subsystem to allow for more threads would still be limited to spawning one new thread, which then worked off the requests sequentially.

Have I misunderstood how that subsystem is supposed to work ? Or is this a restriction to the RESTEasy aspect somehow ? I have in the past used normal WebServlets with concurrency without experiencing this behavior.

Comment: Have you looked into the [async feature](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html). RESTeasy doesn't give much example. You can look at the [Jersey docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html) for more example. It's part of the JAX-RS spec. Note the chunked output in the Jersey doc is not part of the spec, and RESTeasy will not have this support (or should I say classes ).

Comment: Yes, I'm using async, and I can send delayed responses, but I can still only use a single thread.

Comment: I cannot imagine that RESTEasy can be so fundamentally broken that it is restricted to one thread. Are you sure there is no concurrency problem in your application?

Comment: I'm experiencing this behavior in what is very little more than the Wildfly EE7 archetype. There is almost no code at all.

Comment: Well it is possible to have such behaviour even in small apps. For example, if the RestService called a Singleton EJB with Container-managed concurrency...

Comment: If the problem was really on the client side, you could maybe change the title to "Webservice restricted to a single thread?"  (and maybe the tags, too) since it is not Wildfly-specific so that others with this problem can find it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your problem is on the client side. How do you test your code? I have tried to access some REST Service in Wildfly 8.2 by putting a `Thread.sleep(5000)` in some method. If I, for example, open two tabs in Firefox or Chrome, only one request is processed concurrently, and it takes 10 seconds . However, using Firefox and Chrom in parallel, they both get the response in 5 seconds.

Comment: Words cannot express quite how dumb I feel now. Your idea was completely correct. I switched to another testing method (OkHttp) and everything worked exactly as I expected. Thank you, I would have never come up with that based on the things I thought to google.